# How do I run Linux tasks without Docker (on the underlying system)?

Tags: linux, concourse

Tasks `image_resource` property [is marked as optional in the documentation](https://concourse.ci/single-page.html#image_resource), but GNU/Linux tasks fail without it.

Also, the docs for the `type` property of `image_resource` say:

> Required. The type of the resource. Usually `docker-image`

But I couldn't find any information about other supported types.

How can I run tasks on the underlying system without any container technology, like in my Windows and macOS workers?

Answer (score 0):

In Concourse, you really are not supposed to do anything outside of Docker.  That is one of the main features.  Concourse runs in Docker containers and starts new containers for each build.  If you want to run one or more Linux commands in `sh` or `bash` in the container, you can try something like this below, for your task config.

```
  - task: linux
    config:
      platform: linux
      image_resource:
        type: docker-image
        source: {repository: ubuntu, tag: '18.04'}
      run:
        dir: /<path-to-dir>
        path: sh
        user: root
        args:
          - -exc
          - |
            echo "Running in Linux!"
            ls
            scp <you@your-host-machine:file> .
            telnet <your-host-machine>
            <whatever>
            ...
```

Comment: But this is not the case for macOS and Windows workers, right? I have an application that interacts with various hardware peripherals that I want to test on a worker where Docker leads to false positives.

Comment: Concourse is really lacking in documentation here, but `docker-image` is the only type of resource I have ever seen in use.  (But I have not looked for anything else either, since it suits my jobs quite well.)  -  How do you communicate with your hardware on the OS?

Comment: Block devices, USB devices, and bluetooth